# How to get value from children components within parent component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I am building a screen that has a button to add child component, so the user can add more information to the Form.

The parent (the screen) component looks like:

```js
export default function ParentFunction() {
  const [children, setChildren] = useState([<Child></Child>]);

  const addChild = () => {
    var child = [<Child></Child>];

    setChildren((rows) => [...rows, ...child]);
  };

  return (
    ...
    <Form>
      {children}
      <Button onClick={addChild} size="sm" className="mt-3" variant="secondary">
        Add child
      </Button>
    </Form>
    ...
  );
}
```

And the Child component looks like:

```js
export default function Child() {
  const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState();

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Form.Group controlId="formFileLg" className="mb-3">
      <Form.Label>Empresa</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        onChange={(event) => {
          setCompanyName(event.target.value);
        }}
        type="text"
      />
    </Form.Group>
    ...
  );
}
```

I need to be able to, in the Parent component, get data from Child component.

I need to export a PDF with the info of Children components, so I need to do something like this:

```js
export default function ParentFunction() {
  const [children, setChildren] = useState([<Child></Child>]);

  const addChild = () => {
    var child = [<Child></Child>];

    setChildren((rows) => [...rows, ...child]);
  };

  const generatePdf = () => {
    children.forEach((child) => {
      // Here I will do the pdf stuff
      console.log(child.companyName);
    });
  };

  return (
    ...
    <Form>
      {children}
      <Button
        onClick={addChild}
        size="sm"
        className="mt-3"
        variant="secondary"
      >
        Add child
      </Button>
    </Form>
    ...
    <Button
      onClick={generatePdf}
      size="sm"
      className="mt-3"
      variant="secondary"
    >
      Generate PDF
    </Button>
  );
}
```

But the value `child.companyName` is undefined. How can I get value from children components?

Comment: You'll need to either forward a ref for each child, or better, lift the state up to the parent.

Comment: @pilchard Can You give me a idea how to do this? I really don't know how.

Comment: move all your state to parent component and pass it through props in child

Comment: @AmanSadhwani  I can't see how I can control each child state. In the method `addChild` should I create a new state and pass it to the Child?